# How to fetch the key/value pair of a dictionary only containing one item?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have dict. I don't know the key/value inside. How do I get this key and the value without doing a for loop (there is only one item in the dict).

You might wonder why I am using a dictionary in that case. I have dictionaries all over my API and I don't want the user to be lost. It's only a matter of consistency. Otherwise, I would have used a list and indexes.

Comment: A foolish consistency...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the proper data type for the job. Your goal should be to have workable code, not that you use the same data type all over the place.

If your dictionary only contains *one* key and *one* value, you can get either with indexing:

```
key = list(d)[0]
value = list(d.values())[0]
```

or to get both:

```
key, value = list(d.items())[0]
```

The `list` calls are needed because in Python 3, `.keys()`, `.values()` and `.items()` return dict views, not lists.

Another option is to use sequence unpacking:

```
key, = d
value, = d.values()
```

or for both at the same time:

```
(key, value), = d.items()
```

Comment: I tend to unpack iterables using `(value,) = d.values()`

Comment: Every single time I restrain myself not to format it as `a ,= b`, or "the secret unpack-assign operator" :-)

Answer (score 7):

Just get the first item in the dictionary using an iterator

```
>>> d = {"foo":"bar"}
>>> k, v = next(iter(d.items()))
>>> k
'foo'
>>> v
'bar'
```

Comment: Timestamp says you were first. :^)

Comment: +1 Also works nicely in sets - it's also possible if the `dict` is empty to put a default as a parameter to `next` if required...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
>>> d={1:'one'}
>>> k=list(d)[0]
>>> v=d[k]
```

Works in Python 2 or 3

Answer (score 0):

`d.popitem()` will give you a key,value tuple.

Comment: But that'd would remove it from `d` too.

Comment: this is destructive - in addition to getting the key and value it removes it from the dictionary.